# Google Chrome incorrectly calculates the height of the element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

I need to set the height of the sidebar the same as main content, so I wrote this:

```
document.querySelector('.sidebar-left').style.height = document.querySelector('.main-content').offsetHeight + 'px';
```

It works in Firefox like a charm but Google Chrome incorrectly calculates the height of `.main-content` element so the heights of `.sidebar-left` and `.main-content` are not equal. But sometimes when I refresh the page Chrome sets sidebar's height correctly, then again incorrectly.

The same happens when I use `getBoundingClientRect()` method. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment so will post here.

I'm wondering at which point you do this - are you doing this in a document.ready event block (i.e. when the page is fully loaded) or before?

If before then the .main-content may not have yet rendered properly, so getting the height will be incorrect (especially if you're doing some modification of it?)

Comment: I mentioned that in Firefox its ok, so you could guess that the script is executed after DOM ready event.

Comment: The contents may not be fully loaded even at document.ready (do you have any images in it?) - can you check readyState on it to be sure.

Comment: Though this answer is not a to-go solution, it is not incorrect and pointing in the right direction, thus +1. I was facing the same issue with Chrome in a Vue application when calculating offsetHeight for several element during mounted hook. Adding a timeout solved the issue for the moment, though I still need to investigate what exactly may not be rendered properly at this point in time (as it is actually an ul where exactly one li is not calculated correctly).